# How can I mapping Tables embeded in spring boot jpa?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nhibernate-mapping

i have create two table in sql like this:

```
create table dbo.person(
  id int not null identity(1,1),
  code nvarchar(50),
  name nvarchar(250),
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)

create table dbo.employ(
  personId int not null,
  age smallint,
  sex bit,
  PRIMARY KEY (personId),
  FOREIGN KEY (PersonId) REFERENCES Persons(Id)
)
```

how can i pmapping this tables in spring boot jpa?

Comment: You need two entities for answer that question. Do you know what is a class for a entity? Do you know the use of annotations Table, Entity, Id?

Comment: yes i know them. but this tables have special relationship and pesonId are primary key and also foreign key to person table

Comment: Do you really need the personId in second table to be a primary key and a foreign key? Or you can have a Id and a personId?

Comment: yes this is an example and i wand to use employ table as main table in other relationships. for example in accounting system we Create Account table and we need to create and extend Account table in several tables like Account_1, Acount_2 , ... tables that each table have several special fields.